# 500 error on api request. works fine when called through browser

Tags: api, webrequest, webresponse

Hello I have an api which authenticates the user login . Now when I hit this rest service in my browser it displays the result but when I try to do this using my code it gives in 500 error. Please help me with this .

My Api: http://abhinavevent2014.sched.org/api/auth/login?api_key=1309658400d57c8cfc6081f8361de52c&username=abhinavm@test.com&password=test

```
string url = @"http://abhinavevent2014.sched.org/api/auth/login?api_key=1309658400d57c8cfc6081f8361de52c&username=abhinavm@test.com&password=test";


            Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            WebRequest requestfriend = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse responsefriend = requestfriend.GetResponse(); (  This is where it blows)
            Stream streamResponse = responsefriend.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamReaderResponse = new StreamReader(streamResponse, encode);
            jsonResult = streamReaderResponse.ReadToEnd();

            return jsonResult.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you give example output of the failure?

Comment: yikes!  You should not post your api_key on a public forum.

Comment: Did you resolve this??? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `User-Agent` in the headers, as the documentation says:

> You must also send requests with a User-Agent in the headers, as Sched
>   filters out requests with no User-Agent.
>   [Sched API Doc](https://sched.org/api)

Browser automatically does that, so it can retrieve the data.